# Unable to add or modify javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to add or modify a javascript object. My attempts were as below.

```js
var params1 = {};

params1['quanity'] = 200;

params1['currentPrice'] = 1;

localStorage.setItem('keyOfObj', JSON.stringify(params1));

var params = localStorage.getItem('keyOfObj'); // {"quanity":200,"currentPrice":1}

params['quanity'] = 300; // or params.quanity = 300;

params.sellAmount = 230;

console.log(params);
```

None of the above way I couldn't modify the value of quantity or adding a new property of sellAmount. Please noted I am not inside any asynchronous method. So I don't know where I could get wrong. I am highly appreciated anyone who could solve this.

Here actually I am getting the values for params object via localstorage.

Comment: Well your code working (there is typo it is "quantity" not "quanity"), but I tried it in console and everything works. So first, what does not work? What error do you have? And second: is that all your code or you "cut" this part from context? Provide full code (possibly with html) and tell what exact problem you have.

Comment: No still that issue is there. I'll share the full code

Comment: @ZoneDuo  It needs to parse, it's it? Try `var params = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyOfObj'))`

Comment: Actually I did it. But couldn't share the whole code in the question, since it was in two different files. Anyway I have edited the question again as much as I can. Still same result for me

Answer (score 1):

works just fine ! if you can update your question with more details and code, it will be helpful.

```js
var params = {
  "quanity": 200,
  "currentPrice": 1
};

params['quanity'] = 300; // or params.quanity = 300;
params.sellAmount = 230;

//You can use dot syntax to add a new property to it as follows:
//Modifiy works essentially the same way
params.newparam = 555;


console.log(params);
```

Comment: I guess he already adding new parameter in params.sellAmount, as that property was not provided during object initialization.

Comment: Here I am getting values for params object via loacalstorage key. I stored this object in the localstorage.

Comment: @ZoneDuo It needs to parse, it's it? Try `var params = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyOfObj'));`